# When compiling C# expression trees into methods, is it possible to access "this"?

Tags: c#, code-generation, expression-trees

I am trying to dynamically generate a class that implements a given interface. Because of this, I need to implement some methods. I would like to avoid directly emitting IL instructions, so I am trying to use Expression trees and CompileToMethod. Unfortunately, some of these methods need to access a field of the generated class (as if I wrote this.field into the method I am implementing). Is it possible to access "this" using expression trees? (By "this" I mean the object the method will be called on.)

If yes, what would a method like this look like with expression trees?

```cs
int SomeMethod() {
    return this.field.SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

Comment: starting point: `Expression.Constant(this)`, `Expression.PropertyOrField`, `Expression.Call`. You could also use a `ParameterExpression` and pass the `this` in as an argument

Comment: No. `CompileToMethod` does not support compiling to not static methods: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/LambdaExpression.cs,172

Answer (score 2):

`Expression.Constant` or `ParameterExpression` are your friends; examples:

```cs
var obj = Expression.Constant(this);
var field = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, "field");
var call = Expression.Call(field, field.Type.GetMethod("SomeOtherMethod"));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(call);
```

or:

```cs
var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeType));
var field = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, "field");
var call = Expression.Call(field, field.Type.GetMethod("SomeOtherMethod"));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeType, int>>(call, obj);
```

(in the latter case, you'd pass `this` in as a parameter, but it means you can store the lambda and re-use it for different target instance objects)

Another option here might be `dynamic` if your names are fixed:

```cs
dynamic obj = someDuckTypedObject;
int i = obj.field.SomeOtherMethod();
```

Comment: By "this" I mean what would be "this" inside of the generated method (like in the code I provided as example), not the object that generates the code, as Expression.Constant(this) would result in.

Comment: @ZdeněkPavlátka it was just example. You can use any object as a constant if it has field and SomeOtherMethod. So it’s more about bind this instance into actual lambda or pass it as parameter like Marc mentioned

Comment: @ZdeněkPavlátka as Sergey says: just pass the *desired* object in to `Expression.Constant`

Comment: @MarcGravell There is no desired object yet. Desired object will be passed as implicit `this` parameter to the instance method, which OP want to generate thru expression tree.